# Windows Server CALs and SQL CAL required in addition of SharePoint CAL?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, licensing

I would like to know if I have to buy user CAL for Windows Server + SharePoint user CAL, or only SharePoint user CAL is enaugh ?

Same question for MS SQL Server ?
Do I need user CAL in addition ?